# Displaying an image inside of a modal prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery to display a prompt to cancel a WooCommerce subscription. I'd like to add an image on top (possibly center it) on top of the text, and so far I have this code:

```
$logo = 'https://example.org/wp-content/themes/my-theme/img/logo.png';
    $script_atts = array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'promt_msg' => apply_filters( "wcs_cancel_confirmation_promt_msg", __("$logo \nAre you sure you want to cancel your subscription?\nIf so, please type the reason why you want to cancel it here:","wcs-cancel-confirmation" ) ) ,
        'error_msg' => apply_filters( "wcs_cancel_confirmation_error_msg", __("There has been an error when saving the cancellation reason. Please try again.","wcs-cancel-confirmation" ) )
    );
```

Works, but instead of seeing the image, I just get the URL of the image in text form. How can I display the image?

Comment: What kind of prompt does it display? Is it a custom one or the browser prompt?

Comment: It looks like a browser prompt. It's based on this script: https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-subscriptions-cancel-subscription-confirmation/tree/master

Comment: browser prompts only support text for now.

Comment: Ah, that sucks.